# How can I implement this in Android ? (A Customized Line Chart)

Tags: android, charts

[image: A Customized Line Chart]

My question is what would be the **best approach** to implement above line chart in Android.

> I have thought to to use **Horizontal ScrollView** as root. And Add
>   Vertical Linear Layout for each year (maybe 10 of those). Then, I can
>   show up year mark & month mark. Because of Vertical Linear Layout, I
>   can also display the mark point by using layout weight.But, I can't
>   think to any way to connect the dots with that approach.

I have checked out **AChartEngine**. I feel like it is over-bloated with my requirements. If possible, I just want to implement a component with my requirements.

Pls let me know if you have any experience in this. Thanks.

Comment: see http://android-graphview.org/ -- i think it will solve your problem

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-line-chart-using-achartengine/

Comment: Thanks. Now, I am checking up on MPAndroidChart. Will definitely check out the GraphView too.